# How do I include return characters in tbl_regression from gtsummary?

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

I am trying to figure out how to introduce return characters in `tbl_regression` from `gtsummary`. I have tried the following code on R 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 with no luck.

```r
  library(gtsummary)
  library(gt)
  m1 <- glm(response ~ age + stage, trial, family = binomial)
  
  tbl_regression(m1, exponentiate = TRUE,
                 label = list(
                   stage ~ "No\nCR"
                 ))
  
  tbl_regression(m1, exponentiate = TRUE,
                 label = list(
                   stage ~ "Still<br>No<br>CR"
                 ))
  
  tbl_regression(m1, exponentiate = TRUE,
                 label = list(
                   stage ~ html("Still<br>No<br>CR")
                 ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gt::fmt_markdown()` and before doing that we need to convert `gtsummary` table to a `gt` table and then apply `fmt_markdown`  .

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(gt)

m1 <- glm(response ~ age + stage, trial, family = binomial)

tbl_regression(m1, exponentiate = TRUE,
               label = list(
                 stage ~ "No <br> CR"
               )) %>% 
  as_gt() %>% 
  fmt_markdown(columns = everything())
```

Comment: Also curious if there is a way to convert quickly to LaTeX output when the text includes html code?

Comment: Please ask a new question,  so even if I may happen to not know, someone will answer. Thanks.